# Why is there a line of parked cars at the left of the general lane in Otay Mesa Port of Entry?

Tags: usa, driving, borders, mexico, tijuana

I saw a line of parked cars in the general lane in [Otay Mesa Port of Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otay_Mesa_Port_of_Entry) (from Mexico to the US) in early January at night (ca. 4 am). The left lane in the following picture shows the parked car:

[image]

That surprises me as at that stage of the queue I think (perhaps erroneously) that one has to cross the border, and therefore I don't see why one would park there.

Why is there a line of parked cars at the left of the general lane in [Otay Mesa Port of Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otay_Mesa_Port_of_Entry)?

I did see a few people sleeping in some of them: is it a queue of people waiting for some visa/access permits to the US? Or getting a head start on the queue when they wake up to go to work to the US in the morning (in which case why not find a quieter spot to sleep in the US)?

Comment: It's been a while since I crossed into the US (non-essential traveler) but from your picture that appears to be the Ready Lane, not the standard/all cars lane (which is usually just a single lane, sometimes two, between Ready and Sentri at Otay).

Comment: Was this on a Monday morning?  I'm picking they're sleeping in their cars before crossing for the work week.  Monday mornings can be incredibly long waits at the border.

Comment: @Midavalo Tuesday 4am, indeed now that you mention it, it could've been ready lane. Sorry I'm currently blanking and my AT&T in Mexico was so bad it that GMaps didn't record my timeline.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

As often I have no idea why the question got downvoted here as I found some interesting answer on [Reddit](https://redd.it/rvm3cb) from user [i_gotta](https://redd.it/rvm3cb), whom I'll paraphrase.

2 reasons why people park cars at the left of the general lane in Otay Mesa Port of Entry:

- Reason #1: getting a head start on the queue when they wake up to go to work to the US in the morning. People find certain spots of high visibility safe to sleep in their cars.
- Reason #2: people offer a service to bring your car into the line and hold it for you at a certain spot where you can come pick it up. This had become really popular in [Tecate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecate,_Baja_California) until they cracked down on it and also someone was killed in their car there.

Comment: #1 is my pick, esp if it was a Monday morning

Comment: re #2 - I've never seen this at Otay, but it used to be common at El Chaparral (San Ysidro).    Mexico authorities have been cracking down on unlicensed vendors/money makers for the past few months so possibly not as common now

Comment: @Midavalo yes, most folks on https://redd.it/s8v6hu are going with #1 indeed. Though I'd tend to enter the US if I had to sleep in my car, to find a quieter spot. Good to know about  El Chaparral!

Comment: The idea would typically be arrive early at the border in case the line is bad, prepared to wait for hours.  If the line isn't bad, pull over in a relatively safe area for only an hour (or two if the line was particularly quick)  for a short nap before crossing and heading to work.  Easier to stop on this side than the US side